# autorun when tweet me

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I work about twitter API these times. I set cronjob for auto run for my PHP files.

I want to try diffrent thing, I wanna **run PHP file when people tweet me**, and answer to people. Is that possible?

Comment: you mean callback when people tweets to you ?

Comment: @Mit.agile yes my friend

Comment: check this url https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events there you can see this **twttr.events.bind( 'tweet',** i guess this should work.

Comment: follow the above documentation from twitter, it should be there what you want if they provide it.

Comment: @Mit.agile thanks but this function for a web site. like when someone follow me on my website, alert(thanks for follow) him. I don't use a website.

Comment: I think set crons every minute. I afraid about performence

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with IFTTT . https://ifttt.com . It's a free service that you can use to connect social networks and applications. The trigger (the "if" part) for you is channel Twitter, "new mention of you" (the trigger fires everytime you are @mentioned in a tweet) . The "then" part is channel Marker,  which supports an action that allows you to send a request to a specific URL with several options. Method (get, post, delete) content type, and content. Then you have to create a "then" with channel Marker that is configured to make a request to your php script